# Linux process/component sending frequent DNS queries to resolve the local hostname (but shouldn't)

Tags: linux, dns, rhel

I'm not a networking guru so could use some help. I am running a RHEL7 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) VM (Virtual Machine) where **some component on the OS is sending frequent DNS queries to resolve it's own local hostname** to our main DNS server (which shouldn't be happening because the DNS server won't know anything about its address). Can anyone provide guidance as to how I can find out what component/service/process this is? It's filling our logs with 19k records over just hours and I need to find a way to fix this.

The hostname for the RHEL VM is `spe1.2v29999999.dev.local` , there is a static IP on this VM and it is `10.70.49.61`. The /etc/hosts looks like:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1          localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

I suspected it might be a java jar we have running on the VM, but I stopped it via `systemctl stop MyJavaJar` but after running a tcp dump via `tcpdump -i any udp port 53`, I could still see the queries happening.

Here are some examples from different days/times in the logs (both A and TXT records):

```
 2020-05-05T13:53:50.189178+00:00 dns.green.blue.mycompany.com 127.0.0.1 <daemon.info> dnsmasq[20886]: 739 10.70.49.61/65078 query[A] spe1.2v29999999.dev.local from 10.70.49.61

2020-05-07T00:01:39.934899+00:00  dns.green.blue.mycompany.com  127.0.0.1  <daemon.info> dnsmasq[8615]: 27827 10.70.49.61/57348 reply spe1.2v29999999.dev.local is NXDOMAIN

2020-05-11T00:01:20.674688+00:00 dns.green.blue.mycompany.com 127.0.0.1 <daemon.info> dnsmasq[8615]: 130345 10.70.49.61/53321 query[TXT] bootstrap.spe1.2v29999999.dev.local from 10.70.49.61
```

Would making any changes to `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/sysconfig`, `/var/named` .zone files, `/var/named.conf` or `/etc/named` help? Can  I do more with `tcpdump`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

`127.0.0.1 spe1.2v29999999.dev.local`

in /etc/hosts. This is done by default on many distros.

Comment: Does it matter that I am using a static IP on that server, 10.70.49.61?

Comment: If the IP is static you could do either.

Comment: should I be able to do nslookup spe1.2v29999999.dev.local get a result back? I am getting NXDOMAIN when I try to do that. But I can ping spe1.2v29999999.dev.local

I was still seeing the dev.local A and TXT dns queries in the logs. There should be no reboot required correct?

Comment: May be a problem with a local cache like dnsmasq (I don't use it). I did what I recommended for the exact same reason and it fixed it.

Comment: Thank you , I ran service dnsmasq restart and then it started to resolve.